# Structured Streaming 2.1.0 stream to Parquet creates many small files

Tags: apache-spark

I am running Structured Streaming (2.1.0) on a 3-node yarn cluster and stream json records to parquet. My code fragment looks like this:

```
  val query = ds.writeStream
        .format("parquet")
        .option("checkpointLocation", "/data/kafka_streaming.checkpoint")
        .start("/data/kafka_streaming.parquet")
```

I notice it creates thousands of small files quickly for only 1,000 records. I suspect it has to do frequency of trigger. So I changed it:

```
  val query = ds.writeStream
        .format("parquet")
        .option("checkpointLocation", "/data/kafka_streaming.checkpoint")
        .**trigger(ProcessingTime("60 seconds"))**
        .start("/data/kafka_streaming.parquet")
```

The difference is very obvious. Now I can see much smaller number of files created for the same number of records.

My question: Is there any way to have low latency for the trigger and keep smaller number of larger output files?